# Issue with creating class file

Tags: java, class, text, methods, java-7

I am creating a program to read and output baseball statistics. I am trying to create a class file that reads the txt file which consists of the team name followed by 20 batting averages.

I am needing help in making sure that the code i have used reads the text file correctly and how to create the last 3 methods.

Code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballStats {

    private String fileName;
    private String teamName;
    private double[] battingAverage = new double[20];

    public BaseballStats(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        boolean firstLine = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (firstLine) {
                setTeamName(line);
                firstLine = false;
                continue;
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                battingAverage[i] = input.nextDouble();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String newTeamName) {
        teamName = newTeamName;
    }

    public double findMaxAverage() {
        double max = battingAverage[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
            if (battingAverage[i] > max)
                max = battingAverage[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    public double findMinAverage() {
        double min = battingAverage[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
            if (battingAverage[i] < min)
                min = battingAverage[i];
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Txt file :

```
Tars 
0.592
0.427
0.194
0.445
0.127
0.483
0.352
0.190
0.335
0.207
0.116
0.387
0.243
0.225
0.401
0.382
0.556
0.319
0.475
0.279
```

public double spread( )

returns the difference between the highest and lowest batting averages

public int goodPlayers( )

returns the number of players with an average higher than .300

public String toString( )

returns a String containing the team name followed by all the batting averages formatted to three decimal places.

Comment: some one edited your code. Accept it please.

Comment: no one edited it they just removed a tag?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file you are trying to read.

Comment: ok, text file listed above

Comment: What last 3 methods are you talking about in the question ?

Comment: You code looks fine. What exactly is not working about it?

Comment: when i test it the max and min values are 0.0 and the teamName is the name of the file

Comment: last 3 methods are now listed at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created a File object, all you're doing is reading the String filename

```
this.fileName = fileName;
boolean firstLine = true;

try {
    File file = new File(fileName);     // you need to create a File object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);  // then pass that File to the scanner
catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace())
}

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
}
```

With what you're doing, you're reading the String fileName, example "file.txt"

So the Scanner is just reading reading a String "file.txt", not the file

After the String is read, there's nothing left. So all the values in the array remain at 0. That's why you keep getting 0.0 for the result.

**Edit:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseBallStats {

    private String fileName;
    private String teamName;
    private double[] battingAverage = new double[20];

    public BaseBallStats(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        boolean firstLine = true;
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);     // you need to create a File object
            input = new Scanner(file); // then pass that File to the scanner
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (firstLine) {
                setTeamName(line);
                firstLine = false;
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                battingAverage[i] = input.nextDouble();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String newTeamName) {
        teamName = newTeamName;
    }

    public double findMaxAverage() {
        double max = battingAverage[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
            if (battingAverage[i] > max) {
                max = battingAverage[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public double findMinAverage() {
        double min = battingAverage[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < battingAverage.length; i++) {
            if (battingAverage[i] < min) {
                min = battingAverage[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseBallStats stats = new BaseBallStats("file.txt");
        System.out.println(stats.findMaxAverage());
        System.out.println(stats.findMinAverage());
    }

}
```

Comment: i put that in and get an 19 errors found:
Error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations
F

Comment: See My edit. It works for the max average bit not for the min. You may have to fix the logic to find the min

Comment: ok i put in your edit and it compiles with no error but when i run it :java.io.FileNotFoundException: tars.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: nevermind i needed to put the file in the same folder, max does work but am still working on the min

Comment: I found the solution. To the 0.0. You need to delete `continue`. I ran it and it works fine.

Comment: Your logic for the min is fine. What's happening is that the program doesn't read the first average, so there are only 19 inputs instead of 20, leaving the last value in the array to be 0.0.  This happens because of the `continue`. The continue cause the loop not to get the first average. Just delete the `continue` and you're fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42471/discussion-between-user2985542-and-peeskillet)

Answer (score 1):

```
public BaseballStats (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
   this.fileName = fileName;
   File f = new File (fileName);
   Scanner input = new Scanner (f);
   String line = input.nextLine ();
   setTeamName (line);
   int j = 0;
   while (input.hasNextDouble ()) {
       battingAverage[j] = input.nextDouble ();
       j++;
   }
}
```

You can use the above constructor in place of the ones you have used. In order for the Scanner object to read a file, you need to pass a File as a parameter. You were passing a string. You need to create a file object like above.Also, instead of input.hasNextLine() you can use hasNextDouble(), since you only have double values in your file.

For the last 3 methods,

public double spread( )  --  You already have the methods in place for min and max averages. You can declare two variables for each of them(min and max) as global variables and use them in this method to calculate the spread.

public int goodPlayers( )  --  Iterate through the array and fetch the count of players with average higher than .300 just like how you have iterated in the min and max average methods.

public String toString( ) --  You can use StringBuilder class and append the values you need in the string. Check the documentation on [StringBUilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)